# Does taking elements out of a that-clause change the meaning?

Tags: grammar, that

Example sentences I came up with:

> **A)** He told me that I had to do it despite not wanting to.

> **B)** He told me that, despite not wanting to, I had to do it.

> **C**) Despite not wanting to, he told me that I had to do it.

> **D)** He told me that I had to do it, despite not wanting to.

While all the above sentences may have the same meaning, the implicit object of *despite*, in both **C** and **D**, could be understood as *him* instead of *me*. That is,

> **C**) Despite him not wanting to, he told me that I had to do it.

> **D)** He told me that I had to do it, despite him not wanting to.

However, in **A** and **B**, the implicit object could only be understood as *me*.

> **A)** He told me that I had to do it despite him not wanting to. (?)

> **B)** He told me that, despite him not wanting to, I had to do it. (?)

Sometimes, changing the order by putting *despite* in front of the *that*-clause doesn't make sense:

> JS2 regretted that despite the high rate of suicide, there was no national plan for prevention.

> Despite the high rate of suicide, JS2 regretted that there was no national plan for prevention. (?)

Sometimes, it means the same thing:

> He stated that despite those positive developments, important challenges still remained around the country.

> Despite those positive developments, he stated that important challenges still remained around the country.

I think this is because there's a difference between contrasting what's inside a that-clause and contrasting the clause itself.

If my understanding is correct, where could I read more about this from a reputable source? My grammar books don't cover this.

Comment: Yes, ambiguities persist in English. 1B and 1C disambiguate the two senses there. You _can_ also use the clarifying if highfalutin 'He told me that I had to do it, despite my not wanting to' or 'He told me that I had to do it, despite his not wanting to'.

Comment: The ambiguous ones are related to dangling modifiers.

Comment: As @Barmar notes, there is an issue with misplaced modifiers and identifying their referents. However, I had trouble following your argument because you seem to use the word "object" when I think you mean "agent".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I don't understand what you mean by "agent". I learnt that prepositions like *despite* and *of* take objects.

Comment: The agent is basically the person or thing that performs the verb's action (not necessarily its subject). However, I think that I understand now: you're talking about the object of "despite" whereas I'm talking about the agent of "wanting". Usually I'd use a possessive pronoun there, e.g.: "Despite his/my not wanting to . . ."